# \dimexpr gives 0pt

Tags: fonts, tex-core, preamble, pgf-core

Why on earth does the following expression give me `0.0pt`?

```
\edef\x{\the\dimexpr 3ex-1ex\relax}
```

I assume `ex` is a LaTeX unit, as it isn't in the TeXbook. Please where is it defined in the kernel?

**EDIT**

Many thanks for the answers. Ah, Joseph Wright had told me about `\nullfont` in my early days with TeX.

I was trying to complete the list `{A_1ex,A_3ex,A_...,A_10ex}` by using a scheme that is different from (and may be faster than) that used by `\foreach`. `\foreach` can't complete this list or `{A_1pt,A_3pt,A_...,A_10pt}`. The following usually fails:

```
\newcount\cnta
\cnta\z@
\foreach \p in {A_1pt,A_3pt,A_...,A_10pt}{%
  \global\advance\cnta\@ne
  \typeout{Doing \romannumeral\cnta=\p}%
}
```

I made the test in the package and hence `\nullfont` was in effect. I will remove font-dependent units from the permissible units, or make their use conditional on being in document body.

I said "may be faster" above because I have found that `\foreach` looks for ellipsis (`...`) in every element of the list, via:

```
\def\pgffor@scanned{%
  \ifx\pgffor@value\pgffor@stop
    \let\pgffor@next=\pgffor@after
  \else
    \expandafter\pgffor@dots@in@
      \pgffor@value\pgffor@dots@...\pgffor@dots@@\pgffor@stop
    \ifpgffor@dots@in@
      \let\pgffor@next=\pgffor@handledots
    \else
      \let\pgffor@next=\pgffor@handlevalue
    \fi
    <more>
}
```

**EDIT**

In the following definition in `\foreach`, two `\relax` are missing. Or is it deliberate? I don't think so.

```
\def\pgffor@makealphabetic#1{%
  \pgfutil@tempcnta=#1\relax%
  \ifnum\pgfutil@tempcnta>95\relax%
    \advance\pgfutil@tempcnta by-96%
    \expandafter\def\expandafter#1\expandafter%
    {\pgffor@alpha\pgfutil@tempcnta}%
  \else%
    \advance\pgfutil@tempcnta by-64%
    \expandafter\def\expandafter#1\expandafter%
    {\pgffor@Alpha\pgfutil@tempcnta}%
  \fi%
}
```

**EDIT** (2012/09/08)

In

```
{A_1ex, A_3ex, A_..., A_10ex}
```

my scheme recovers and uses `ex` (the original unit) in the completed/filled list. As percusse has pointed out, PGF's scheme requires

```
{A_1ex, A_3ex, A_...ex, A_10ex}
```

My scheme can also parse, e.g.,

```
{A_1pt-2bp*3+(3cc-2ex)/2, A_1pt-3bp*3+(3cc-2ex)/2, A_..., A_1pt-12bp*3+(3cc-2ex)/2}
```

but, because parsing this type of expression is expensive and unlikely to be passed by any user, I haven't included it in the relevant macros. I have retained it in the package
as a future tool. What makes, e.g., `1pt-2bp*3+(3cc-2ex)/2` expensive to parse is the need to safely confirm that it is 'dimensionable'. A simple counter or dimension assignment will not always work in this case. I welcome some ideas in this regard.

One point: you can't reconstitute the syntax

```
1pt-2bp*3+(3cc-2ex)/2
```

after evaluation. Even PGF's scheme can't conceivably do it, for what are you going to put at the positon of X in

```
{A_1pt-3bp*3+(3cc-2ex)/2, A_1pt-9bp*3+(3cc-2ex)/2, A_...X, A_1pt-27bp*3+(3cc-2ex)/2}
```

There is not one unit (like `pt` or `ex`) to retain.

Maybe there is a need for something like

```
{A_1pt-3bp*3+(3cc-2ex)/2, A_1pt-9bp*3+(3cc-2ex)/2,
  A_...1pt-?bp*3+(3cc-2ex)/2, A_1pt-27bp*3+(3cc-2ex)/2}
```

Note `?`. But won't that go ridiculously too far? TeX isn't theory.

Comment: This `\documentclass{article}

\edef\x{\the\dimexpr 3ex-1ex\relax}

\begin{document}

\x

\end{document}` reports `8.61108pt`. Am I missing something?

Comment: See **Appendix F** (page  433) of *The TeXbook* for `\fontdimen5` and the values of 1ex (x-height).

Comment: @AhmedMusa Where exactly are you using this? Do you have a font loaded at the time, or is `\nullfont` active?

Comment: It is in the TeXbook, with five mentions in the index.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The internal unit `ex` is explained in the TeXbook as follows:

> ex is the "x-height" of the current font.

It is taken from `\fontdimen5`, as explained in Appendix F. So the value depends on the font.

```
\nullfont\edef\x{\the\dimexpr 3ex-1ex\relax}
\show\x
```

gives

```
> \x=macro:
->0.0pt.
```

If you use `ex` in LaTeX *before* `\documentclass`, you get `0pt` as no font is selected at that time.

Also, there might be documentclasses (like `minimal`) *where no font is selected even until `\begin{document}`*!

Anyway, even if some font has been selected by `\documentclass`, you don't really know for sure which one, as the "real" initialisation of the document happens in `\begin{document}`.

So, be careful with font-dependent units like `ex` or `em` unless you know what the current font is!

(Thanks to Barbara Beeton for pointing out this problem!)

Comment: since the definition is in the preamble, no fonts are ordinarily selected before `\begin{document}`.  that's why `\nullfont` is relevant (which isn't really clear to a newbie from the explanation as it now stands).

Comment: @barbarabeeton What exactly do you mean? With `\documentclass{article}
\edef\x{\the\dimexpr 3ex-1ex\relax}
\show\x` I get `8.61108pt`.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Indeed the value is `0pt` before `\documentclass`. I made an update.

Comment: try it with `\documentclass{minimal}`.  depends on the `\documentclass`, and that wasn't specified in the question.

Comment: @barbarabeeton You're right, of course. I tried to give some more helpful advice.

Answer (score 6):

`\foreach` can complete that list if you add `ex` or `pt` after the ellipsis. Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\makeatletter
\newcount\cnta
\cnta\z@
\foreach \p in {A_1ex,A_2ex,A_...ex,A_10ex}{%
  \global\advance\cnta\@ne
  \typeout{Doing \romannumeral\cnta=\p}%
}


\begin{document}
.
\end{document}
```

Same applies to `pt` too.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that. That means the list completion scheme of `\foreach` is simpler than I had thought: the user has to give all the clues. I now have a scheme that takes `{A_1ex,A_3ex,A_...,A_10ex}`. And even `{A_1ex,A_3ex,...,A_10ex}`, with the key `grow right` or `grow=right`. But I have to revisit `{A_1ex,A_3ex,A_...ex,A_10ex}`, although the syntax is not something I like.

Comment: Oh I remember your solution from an earlier question. As my supervisor says a bit of ignorance helps to supersede the known ones. Probably, you wouldn't have that solution if this tip was available to you. :)

Comment: I have looked at the `\foreach` code again. `\foreach` attempts to grow only numbers and characters, not dimensions or lengths. That is rather easy, but the use syntax seems (to me, anyway) to be weird. The dilemma I face is that if you simplify the use syntax, then internal parsing becomes more complicated. With `{A_1ex,A_3ex,A_...,A_10ex}`, my scheme assumes that everything on the right of `_` is to be grown.  With `{A_1ex,A_3ex,...,A_10ex}`, the user has to suggest `link=_` and `grow=right`. But my scheme takes all sorts of list separators, even active parsers and subparsers.

Comment: Eg, `\newforeach[parser=\do] \x:\y in {1:a\do 2:b\do 3:c}`. `\do` may be used as a list processor in contexts outside `\newforeach`. The subparser `:` is detected automatically, but it can also be suggested by the user.

Comment: @AhmedMusa That's quite neat but then how would you avoid ambiguous entries such as `{A_1ex2pt,A_3ex2pt,A_...,A_10ex2pt}` would understand that it's just an appending 2 pt? (Not that it's relevant but suppose there are two disjoint number groups to the right for some reason)

Comment: Who will submit that? TeX can't evaluate and grow `1ex2pt`. This is syntactically problematic. `1ex+2pt` makes sense, but the outcome will not preserve the split between `1ex` and `2pt`. I am sure you'll agree that every medication is only a step towards preserving the quality of life, not a magic. And every medicine has a side effect.

Comment: @AhmedMusa Sure. Again, I think it's neat trick. I merely pointed out that the right side of the ellipsis might be required occasionally.